# SHBrowseForFolder for drive selection only

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I'm curious if "Browse For Folder" default selector available through [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be adjusted to pick drives only?

Something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: [Use `IFolderFilter`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/14/10456386.aspx). Closely related to [SelectFolderDialog with only drives, no folder selection inside drives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728596/selectfolderdialog-with-only-drives-no-folder-selection-inside-drives/19736016#19736016).

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thank you, Raymond. I can't seem to figure out though how to differentiate between root of a drive vs. plain folders in the `IFolderFilter::ShouldShow` method. Note that I can't use `SHCreateItemWithParent` because I need this to run on XP as well.

Comment: You can check if the parent folder is My Computer.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Hmm. I wish I saw it earlier :) I actually went with `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf(SHGDN_FORPARSING)` and then `StrRetToBuf` and `PathIsRoot` that will return `TRUE` if I want to keep that item. The issue is how to let root "Computer" entry through. Do I have to do `IShellFolder::CompareIDs(SHCIDS_CANONICALONLY)` on each item that is passed to `IFolderFilter::ShouldShow` -- is there an easier way?

Comment: That would work. Not sure what"easier way" you are looking for. You want to know if it is equal to My Computer, so at some point somebody needs to do a comparison.

Comment: @RaymondChen: :) No, I meant comparing a GUID to GUID. `IShellFolder::CompareIDs` has too many gotchas. But thanks anyway!